# Reverse String inside a While Loop

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I just started learning Java and I'm doing a little program to convert a decimal number into binary numbers using only `while` loops.

The results were reversed, therefore I'm using a method to reverse the string. But the reverse method does not work for me. Could anyone help me, please?

The following is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner getnumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int originalnum = getnumber.nextInt();
        int remainder;
        String binary_temp;
        if (originalnum % 2 != 0) {
            while (originalnum > 0) {
                remainder = originalnum % 2;
                originalnum /= 2;
                binary_temp = String.valueOf(remainder);
                String binarynum = new StringBuffer(binary_temp).reverse().toString();
                System.out.print(binarynum);
            }
        }
        else if (originalnum % 2 == 0) {
            while (originalnum > 0) {
                originalnum /= 2;
                remainder = originalnum % 2;
                binary_temp = String.valueOf(remainder);
                String binarynum = new StringBuffer(binary_temp).reverse().toString();
                System.out.print(binarynum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(originalnum));`

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Names should be camelCase not snake_case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But the reverse method does not work for me.

That's because you are reversing a string that contains a single digit. If you run your code through a debugger, you will discover that. Every programmer needs to know how to debug code, including code written by other people.

You need to build up the string of binary digits using a single `StringBuffer` and only after the `while` loop you reverse the string.

Also, from the code in your question:

```java
if (originalnum % 2 != 0) {
```

If the above condition is **not** true, then `originalnum % 2` **must** be zero, hence not need for `if-else`, i.e. (also from the code in your question):

```java
else if (originalnum % 2 == 0) {
```

You just need `else` by itself.

However, you don't need that `if-else` at all. You just need a single `while` loop and a single `StringBuffer`. Actually, for a single-threaded program – such as yours – it is better to use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). And rather than creating a new `StringBuffer` and reversing it on each iteration of the `while` loop, you can simply [insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,int)) the [binary] digit.

(More notes after the code.)

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumberConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner getnumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int originalnum = getnumber.nextInt();
        originalnum = Math.abs(originalnum);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (originalnum == 0) {
            sb.append('0');
        }
        else {
            while (originalnum > 0) {
                int remainder = originalnum % 2;
                sb.insert(0, remainder);
                originalnum /= 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

- I assume that you only want to handle positive numbers, hence the call to method `abs`.
- The `while` loop does not handle the case where `originalnum` is 0 (zero), hence the `if (originalnum == 0)`

Have you seen Oracle's [Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)?

I also recommend the book [Java by Comparison](https://java.by-comparison.com/) by Simon Harrer, Jörg Lenhard & Linus Dietz.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop and server your string , here is example

```
public class StringFormatter {  
public static String reverseString(String str){  
    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();  
    String rev="";  
    for(int i=ch.length-1;i>=0;i--){  
        rev+=ch[i];  
    }  
    return rev;  
}  
}
```

Comment: This does not handle strings containing surrogate pairs correctly. It's not efficient either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one line to reverse the string

```
String reversedString = (new StringBuilder().append(oldString).reverse().toString());
```